# Django going to external website with my variables in url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a model and i want to go to a external website with my variables in the url . For example: "www.example.com\ {% object.field %} .com

**My model**

```html
class Avaria(models.Model):
    freguesia = models.ForeignKey(Freguesia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Freguesia")
    rua = models.ForeignKey(Rua, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Rua")
```

I'm changing my `change_form_object_tools.html` and add a extra `li` to do something like this:

```html
<li>
    <a href="https://example.com\{% obj.freguesia%}\{% obj.rua%}">{% trans "Example" %</a>
</li>
```

If i use the `original.pk` it is working but i want to use another field that is not the `primary key`

Comment: I think you want something like `{{ obj.freguesia.name }}\{{ obj.rua.name }}`. Check answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting correct `object` in variable `obj` then

instead of

```
<a href="https://example.com\{% obj.freguesia%}\{% obj.rua%}">{% trans "Example" %</a>
```

you need to do

```
<a href="https://example.com\{{ obj.freguesia }}\{{ obj.rua }}">{% trans "Example" %</a>
```

I know in django admin model object comes in variable `original`, you can use `original` in place of `obj`.

Also if you want to understand django template language

> `{{ }}` for rendering variables and using filters, [read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#variables)
>
> `{% %}` for sentences such as if and for or to call tags such as load, static, etc. is for tags, [read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#tags)
>
> Similarly there is `{#  #}` for comments.

Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/) please